# Linux Jupyter Notebook : "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using  the PYNQ Linux on Zedboard and when I tried to run a code on Jupyter Notebook to load a model.h5 I got an error message:

"The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"

I tried to upgrade keras and Jupyter but still have the same error

I don't know how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Model is too large to be loaded into memory so kernel has died.